# PC startup issue: Can a video card short damage a motherboard?

Tags: boot

My PC was working fine until the last time I used it around 2 years ago. When I took it out of hibernation a few days ago, it would not start up. Upon pressing the power button the first time, all the leds came on for a brief moment and then went out. After that, pressing the power button had no effect at all unless I turned off the power supply or disconnected the power cable for ~10 seconds and reconnected it. Then the same thing would happen; one time only, the leds would flicker on for a split second and then nothing.
I began disconnecting connectors and found that the computer would fire up with the ATX12V connector disconnected. I hunted for a short and found a literal bug on the video card (see linked pic).

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joHc0.jpg)

I removed the bug and reconnected everything. The computer now starts up. All leds and case fans run, but I get no video. Also, the fan on the video card pulses on and off approximately once a second.
This pulsing of the fan does not take place if the ATX12V connector is disconnected; it runs at a consistent speed, but still no video.

I tried the video card in another PC and it works fine.
I disconnected everything from ram to hard drives to usb ports and I replaced the BIOS battery, but the fan pulsing persists unless the ATX12V connector is disconnected. Only then does the fan run normally, but of course, no video still.
I suspect a failed MOSFET at this point, but that usually happens due to overheating

Is it possible for a MOSFET to overheat instantly from stone cold in a single voltage spike?
Any other suggestions or observations would be appreciated.

The motherboard is a Gigabyte GA 970A UD3

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question in the title, "Can a video card short damage a motherboard?" The answer is yes. As strange as it is, you are not the first person to have a literal bug bridge two connection on a PCB and short out a device.  There are many examples of this, here is [one](https://hackaday.com/2018/06/05/sonoff-postmortem-finds-bugs-literally/).  You are fortunate, that it seems the video card is undamaged.  However, your motherboard might be.  That bug could have bridged the connectors and caused a voltage spike, higher voltage, or allowed two much current to flow through through the motherboard.

As for your second question about the MOFSET, that leaves the scope of computers and this site and enters electrical engineering.

Personally, unless you are familiar with electronics and testing, not to mention having time, I would just buy a replacement motherboard.  You could go down an endless rabbit hole trying to troubleshoot something as complex as a modern motherboard.